# Healthcare IT Fire Sale - Question Adoption

Tags: discussion, on-topic, off-topic

As some (maybe many) of us are aware, the [Healthcare IT](http://healthcareit.stackexchange.com/) site will be shutting down in the very near future.

The folks over there have identified some questions we might be able to give a home to, so I'm submitting them here for a (hopefully) quick consensus.

---

**Question 1:** [What are some benefits and challenges to the application of cloud computing in healthcare environments?](http://healthcareit.stackexchange.com/questions/188/what-are-some-benefits-and-challenges-to-application-of-cloud-computing-in-healt)


Basically a typical cloud computing question, but with a slant toward talking about requirements specific to the healthcare industry (HIPAA-style confidentiality laws and such)

I think there's enough interesting information here that it's worth preserving, even if it's not our typical on-topic question.

---

**Question 2:** [Is it necessary to run a webserver to attain CCHIT certification](http://healthcareit.stackexchange.com/questions/145/is-it-necessary-to-run-a-webserver-to-attain-cchit-certification)
This one seems a little niche, I find it interesting personally but that's probably because I'm half-in the healthcare industry these days.

---

**Question 3:** [setting up PACSone server, web viewer, and uploader](http://healthcareit.stackexchange.com/questions/862/setting-up-pacsone-server-web-viewer-and-uploader)
I think we would normally whack this one as a shopping question -- I'm not sure there's really an answer that's not either a list of products or "Sorry, you probably need to talk to the vendor/write it yourself"

---

Out of the three do we like any enough to give them a home (either "alive" or "locked for historical reasons"?)

Comment: There was a Healthcare IT site?

Comment: @WesleyDavid http://healthcareit.stackexchange.com Yep.

Comment: I'll take a wander on over and see what I can find.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 Thanks for having a look.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 Mark took a look through and found a couple, so no need to go through unless you'd like to.

Comment: @WesleyDavid Yep, it was ill conceived and destined to tank from get-go.

Answer (score 5):

If Question 1 had been asked directly on SF, it would have been jumped on and closed as Not A Real Question. Should we allow it just because it's interesting? I say no.

Question 2 seems... borderline. I have no idea what the hell they're talking about though, so who knows.

Question 3 is certainly shopping, and has an awful lot of industry-specific jargon, so I suspect its value would be minimal.

---

On another note, I suspect anothe reason why a lot of those questions are a very poor fit for SF (or any site) is because Healthcare IT is hugeeeely dependant on where you live and the regulations and laws that are in place. We don't like localised questions like that here.

Comment: I totally understand where you are coming from.  Thanks for looking at these.  Have a look at anything else you might like and flag if it's something you want.

Comment: (Or if you don't feel like picking through, which is understandable, if you could look at some of our tags and identify those that might have high probability of on-topic questions, and I can weed through)

Comment: @jonsca - sure, I'll have a poke around there today and flag anything I like the looks of.

Comment: Thank you for doing so!

Comment: Too bad we couldn't close the first as A Very Bad Idea, because they could have ended up with [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=65649&tstart=0).

Comment: @tombull89 O_o that's just incredible. I can't believe anyone would be that stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 - NARQ
Q2 - Migrate
Q3 - Shopping

Two out of three should have been closed anyway... Doesn't give me much confidence in anything else the site may have. I'm all for migrating anything/everything that fits SF, but the site seems rife with crap.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mark and Chris about 1 and 3 but not 2.

Q2 has absolutely nothing to do with system administration or related matters. I'm just not sure whether it would be OT, NC or TL.